# CString to LPCTSTR conversion breaks sql query

Tags: c++, atl, c-strings

I have a part of larger sql query stored as LPCTSTR

```
LPCTSTR var = _T(" SELECT ...");
```

and it works fine. I need to modify the query with a variable, so I'm trying

```
CString sqlQuerry = _T(" SELECT ... %s");
CString sqlString, stringVar = _T("variable");

sqlString.Format(sqlQuerry, stringVar);

var = (LPCTSTR)sqlString; // var is LPCTSTR type
```

var looks fine when i watch it in debugger, but when I'm running the application, the output window shows weird characters instead of my query (°YQ).

I removed the modifying part, so now it's just

```
CString sqlQuerry = _T(" SELECT ...");
var = (LPCTSTR)sqlQuerry;
```

but still, weird characters in debug output. It looks like encoding problem for me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have your unicode flag switched on?  What happens when you change to MBCS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var = (LPCTSTR)sqlString; // var is LPCTSTR type
```

What are you doing with `var` later on? When `sqlString` loses scope, `var` points to garbage. This is no copying, `var` is just a pointer to the `sqlString` internal buffer.

That said, use bind parameters. Do not use any kind of string format on SQL strings. Really. Use bind parameters. Google it [or use wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Make [little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) proud.

Comment: thanks, that's it, sqlString out of scope. shame on me